# Can't add SpriteCanvasMaterial in three.js r94

Tags: canvas, three.js

```
const particleMaterial = new THREE.SpriteCanvasMaterial({
    color: 0x000000,
    program: function(context) {
        context.beginPath();
        context.font = 'bold 20px Arial';
        context.fillStyle = '#058';
        context.transform(-1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
        context.rotate(Math.PI);
        context.fillText(wordFont, 0, 0);
    }
});
const particale = new THREE.Sprite(particleMaterial);
this.scene.add(particale);
```

#### The code above cause an error.

#### I just want to add some canvas shapes to three.js scene.

[image]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/49157388/1461008